# Why can't I use DVD drive to install in KVM?

Tags: centos, rhel, kvm, vmware-workstation, nested-virtualization

## Summary

I'm currently training for RHCSA. I have to install few servers with KVM.

I'm unable to select the DVD drive to install the OS (greyed out). While I can install by other means, I'm curious to know why I can't this way.

[image]

## My setup

That's the tricky part.

My KVM host is a VMware Workstation guest.

The DVD is correctly mounted in OS, I can browse it from GUI and CLI.

## Question

Why am I unable to chose DVD Drive ?

Is it because of the nested Virtualization ?

Is it some security setting in KVM ?

Comment: Read this: https://serverfault.com/questions/612547/why-has-cd-dvd-host-passthrough-been-disabled-in-centos-7-rhel-7 and this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=760885